# Printing SHA256 sum

Tags: c, sha256

I am trying to build a C program to find an unknown string equivalent to a given SHA256 sum. The final program should generate strings of the format "###ENCRYPTION," then find it's SHA sum and compare to the known value. However, I am having problems simply generating the SHA sum. For some reason, my method of printing the sum drops out 1 character:

```
000ENCRYPTION=f6bc212596f37e1855fb2bbfaf49b514c5ea79e332c57bb6**0**c493bafd38baff5
```

But my code generates:

```
000ENCRYPTION=f6bc212596f37e1855fb2bbfaf49b514c5ea79e332c57bb6c493bafd38baff5
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699268/im-generating-a-sha256-hash-of-few-files-and-some-of-them-return-63-characters?rq=1) seems to seems to describe a similar problem but it does not quite fit my problem.

I have already built a program in Python to do the same thing, but now I want to build one in C to compare run times.
(I also used the CommonCrypto Library from OS X  but OpenSSL would work too.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
int c=0;
char *input_sum="9dcaea0ae17e31d47640cb7c390976d8962823a55ea03fe43b0d061f5624069f"; // currently unused
char *end="ENCRYPTION";
char temp[100]; // need to learn more about allocating memory
unsigned char output[32]; // initializes output variable

printf("Sum=f6bc212596f37e1855fb2bbfaf49b514c5ea79e332c57bb60c493bafd38baff5\n"); // Sum of 000ENCRYPTION from command line

while( c < 5 ) { // limited to 5 right now for testing
    sprintf(temp, "%03d", c); // creates leading zeros
    sprintf(temp + 3, "%s", end); // appends string "end"; should ideally be moved outside loop
    c++;
    puts(temp); // visual check of input into cc_sha256

    CC_SHA256(temp, (CC_LONG)strlen(temp), output); // function does sha256sum

    int i; // for loop prints resulting byte array from cc_sha256 to hex; I believe the problem is here
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%x", output[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It compiles either way. I put both to try to increase visibility

Comment: You do realize that finding a given string that hashes to a particular SHA256 hash will likely require on average 2^256 trials, I presume? Finding two different strings that hash to the same value would be slightly easier, but still on average will require 2^255 trials... Even if you can try 1,000,000,000 per second, that's going to require on the order of 1.8*10^60 years to complete...

Comment: In this case, the format of the hashed string is known (###ENCRYPTION), so 1000 tries will be needed at most.

Answer (score 0):

Where the output should be `0c`, your code only outputs the `c` part. This is because `printf` by default prints the result with the minimum number of characters possible. In this case, you should tell `printf` that the proper result always contains two hexadecimal digits by giving it a width, and by specifying that a zero should be placed in the most-significant nibble if the input is less than `0x10`:

```
printf("%02x", output[i]);
```

Comment: Tried that. Now it just outputs a space where a zero should be

Comment: @user6023571 - Sorry for the mistake, I edited my answer.

Comment: Alternatively, and in some circles preferably, `%.2x` does the same job (using `.` instead of `0`).  I'm not hung up on it; I use `0` as often as I do `.` (more historically, less recently — I'm gently migrating towards `%.2x` rather than `%02x`).

Comment: Any particular reason for that?